# Detect a custom ArUco marker ( latest version )

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, aruco

```
custom_marker_path = "custom_marker_empty_square.jpg"
custom_marker_image = cv.imread(custom_marker_path)
custom_marker = 

param_markers = cv.aruco.DetectorParameters()

images_list = read_images("../images/augmentation")

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
#marker_dict = cv.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv.aruco.DICT_4X4_50)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    gray_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    marker_corners, marker_IDs, reject = cv.aruco.detectMarkers(gray_frame, custum_marker, parameters=param_markers)
```

I have an image of my own marker and I want to detect it directly without using an ArUco dictionary, or creating a new dictionary and add this marker to this dictionary, or add this new marker to the PreDefinedDictionary